# How to get rid the weird characters in the output of the minicom?

Tags: serial-port, timestamp, special-characters, tee

I am using the following command to log the data from minicom (serial port) with timestamp:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600 | ( while read line; do echo "$(date +%Y%m%d:%H%M%S), ${line}"; done )| tee -a out.txt
```

The logged data in the out.txt file is:

```
20151006:145139, [20;47H [21;1H1 some data
20151006:145140, [20;47H [21;1H2 some data
20151006:145141, [20;47H [21;1H3 some data
20151006:145142, [20;47H [21;1H4 some data
20151006:145143, [20;47H [21;1H5 some data
20151006:145144, [20;47H [21;1H6 some data
```

I thing that the weird characters "[20;47H [21;1H"are the carriage return and the line length, I want the output to be saved on the out.txt as in the following:

```
20151006:145139, 1 some data
20151006:145140, 2 some data
20151006:145141, 3 some data
20151006:145142, 4 some data
20151006:145143, 5 some data
20151006:145144, 6 some data
```

Answer (score 0):

Those "weird characters" are Cursor Movement escape sequences in your case.

see http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html
or 
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

They are shown because you are piping the output which should be going to your terminal.

If you are not interested in those characters you might want to use the `--capturefile` parameter.

To prepend a date I'd use a fifo.

```
mkfifo logFifo
cat logFifo | while read line; do echo "$(date +%Y%m%d_%T.%N) | ${line}"; done >> out.txt &
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600 --capturefile logFifo
```

*I just changed the date format how I use it*

To stop you need to quit `minicom` get the `cat`-command to foreground with `fg` and then terminate it with `CTRL-c`
then just remove the fifo again `rm logFifo`